# Firebase data:set error: "Could not parse auth token."

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm getting the following error when I try to use data:set in my CircleCI build with token authentication. I'm using exactly the same token (it's stored in an environment variable) with deploy and it works fine.

```
-> % firebase data:set -f ... --token='...' /content data.json --non-interactive --confirm


Error: Could not parse auth token.
```

Comment: are you found solution?? if yes then can you please share?